# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

Running an SSIS package in SSDT. Constantly getting the error:

```
The request OLEDB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 is not registered.
```

When trying to insert data from an OLE DB source to an Excel Destination.

I have tried this with the 2010 32 bit Access Database engine, 2016 32 bit Access Database Engine, and the 64 bit database engine in both 2010 and 2016.

All 4 installations were unsuccessful in fixing the problem. Here is my connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";
```

I have also tried both 64bit SSIS Runtime and 32 bit.

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Comment: Did you check if the provider is registered with your system? (COM) You could use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html

Comment: I have no idea what I'm supposed to look for to verify whether the provider is registered.

Comment: SSDT runs as a 32 bit process so focus on the 32 bit driver for now. To see if this provider is installed, create a blank file, change the extension to UDL, double click it,and see if there is a similiar provider in the list. Fill in all the details, press OK then open the file in notepad and take a look at the connection string. Did you build this connection string from within SSDT or did you get it from somewhere else?